# Proof: $\sqrt {a^2-b^2}$ irrational

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to prove that the following expression is irrational:
$$ \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

$$ 
\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac a b
\\
x^2+1=\left(\frac a b\right)^2=\frac {a^2} {b^2 }
\\ 
x^2=\frac {a^2} {b^2 } -1
\\
x=\sqrt{\frac {a^2} {b^2 } -1}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2} }
\\
\frac {\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} {\sqrt{b^2 }}
\\
x=\frac {\sqrt{a^2-b^2} }b
$$

Here is where I get stuck. I know that to prove that it is irrational I must prove that $$\sqrt {a^2-b^2} $$ is not a rational expression.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. As written what you are trying to prove is false. If $a=5$ and $b=3$ then $c= \sqrt{a^2 - b^2} = 4$ is rational. You may be trying to work with Pythagorean triples. If so, start by looking that up on wikipedia. If you want to clarify your question, [edit] it. Don't respond in comments.

Comment: Please make the body of your MSE question self-contained. Don't rely on the title to provide important information. Here the body of your question suggests you are trying to prove something different from what the title says and hence you have got two conflicting answers.

Answer (score 4):

What about $$a=5,b=4,c=3$$
I think the assumption that this is irrational is wrong, or maybe just needs more context

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this answer, though literally correct, isn't vary useful, As you note, the OP has probably not correctly stated the question. I'm glad you want to help - this particular help would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are on a wrong track.

If you know an algebraic proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational you can generalize it to show that the square root of an integer is rational if and only if it is the square of an integer*. Since adding $1$ to a square (other than $0$) can't produce a square you're done.

*Hint. Write $a/b$ in lowest terms. Then show that every prime that divides $a$ must divide $n^2 + 1$ twice.